# ZIP file and folder in directory then return to the download url w/Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a download zip file from the directory which is first i have to zip the subdir and files from the path below. I use zipObj.write(filePath). After zip the file, how to return the zip file to the href="{% url 'images' path=/mnt/transmission/2020/3/16/1/ %} in the button download so that I can download the zipfile?

```
import os
import zipfile

#this is my path
/mnt/transmission/2020/3/16/1/

#In the 1/
There is sub folder and files. I want to zip this sub folder files.

#views.py
def downloadIMG(request, path):
"""
Function to download zip file
"""
with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
    with zipfile.ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
            print subdirs
            for file in files:
                filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                zipObj.write(filePath)
                print zipObj

    response = HttpResponse(zipObj, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(path)
    return response

#html
<a href="{% url 'images' path=/mnt/transmission/2020/3/16/1/ %}" id="myButton" style="border-radius: 50px; width: 138px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-b-10 pull-right"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bold">{% trans "Download" %}</span></a>

#url.py
url(r'^rundownload/(?P<path>.*)', views.downloadIMG, name='images'),
```

I get this error instead:
I get this error '[Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/mnt/transmission/2020/3/16/1/' '

Comment: Subdirectories should be recursively accessed.

Comment: @NilankaManoj Im sorry. Would you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!

Your question is not formulated as a question (but as a statement).

Please edit your question according to SO's guidelines for 
[asking questions, found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you avoid getting your question down-voted.

Also, it's quite hard to figure out what you're really asking.

What do you mean by *"i have to zip the subdir and files from the directory and then return to the download url"*? Where did the URL become part of the context? 
Do you mean the downloaded file's PATH?

Comment: In your case, sub-directories are only available in the same level without nested(sub-sub-..-directories) ????

Comment: @cseder Yes, I want to return to the href download button , So that i can download the zipfile. I have edited my questions. That you so much for the comment.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @SaisivaA Yes. The zip file does not return to the download url. I get this error '[Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/mnt/transmission/2020/3/16/1/' '